# de-duplicate timeindex by adding milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use time datetime as main index, but have a lots of duplicates there. What I want is to add artificial milliseconds that works as “counter” inside each group of seconds.

For example – the original dataframe looks like:

```
                         Bid  BidVol
2016-06-27 13:00:10  4183.50       0
2016-06-27 13:00:10  4183.50       0
2016-06-27 13:00:10  4183.50       0
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4249.25       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4249.25       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4249.00       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4248.75       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4248.75       2
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4248.75       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10  4248.75       2
2016-06-28 13:00:12  4248.50       0
2016-06-28 13:00:12  4248.50       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12  4354.00       1
2016-06-30 13:00:10  4394.00       0
2016-06-30 13:00:11  4394.25       1
2016-06-30 13:00:11  4394.00       0
```

My goal is to change duplicit rows to:

```
2016-06-28 13:00:10
2016-06-28 13:00:10.001000
2016-06-28 13:00:10.002000
2016-06-28 13:00:10.003000
2016-06-28 13:00:10.004000
2016-06-28 13:00:10.005000
2016-06-28 13:00:10.006000
```

I was trying to play with groupby function, that I can use to print the miliseconds with loop:

```
for name, group in test.groupby(test.index):
    print ('------')
    i=0
    for idx, values in group.iterrows():
        print (idx+pd.Timedelta(milliseconds=i))
        i+=1
```

However I do not know how to change the index the most effective way to get the result I need? Especially with efficiency on mind (the main dataset is very big).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for creating `ms` , convert it [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to `index`:

```
a = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
print (a)
2016-06-27 13:00:10    0
2016-06-27 13:00:10    1
2016-06-27 13:00:10    2
2016-06-28 13:00:10    0
2016-06-28 13:00:10    1
2016-06-28 13:00:10    2
2016-06-28 13:00:10    3
2016-06-28 13:00:10    4
2016-06-28 13:00:10    5
2016-06-28 13:00:10    6
2016-06-28 13:00:12    0
2016-06-28 13:00:12    1
2016-06-29 13:00:12    0
2016-06-29 13:00:12    1
2016-06-29 13:00:12    2
2016-06-29 13:00:12    3
2016-06-29 13:00:12    4
2016-06-29 13:00:12    5
2016-06-29 13:00:12    6
2016-06-29 13:00:12    7
2016-06-29 13:00:12    8
2016-06-29 13:00:12    9
2016-06-30 13:00:10    0
2016-06-30 13:00:11    0
2016-06-30 13:00:11    1
dtype: int64
```

```
df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(a, unit='ms')
print (df)
                             Bid  BidVol
2016-06-27 13:00:10.000  4183.50       0
2016-06-27 13:00:10.001  4183.50       0
2016-06-27 13:00:10.002  4183.50       0
2016-06-28 13:00:10.000  4249.25       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10.001  4249.25       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10.002  4249.00       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10.003  4248.75       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10.004  4248.75       2
2016-06-28 13:00:10.005  4248.75       1
2016-06-28 13:00:10.006  4248.75       2
2016-06-28 13:00:12.000  4248.50       0
2016-06-28 13:00:12.001  4248.50       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12.000  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12.001  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12.002  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12.003  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12.004  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12.005  4353.75       0
2016-06-29 13:00:12.006  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12.007  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12.008  4354.00       1
2016-06-29 13:00:12.009  4354.00       1
2016-06-30 13:00:10.000  4394.00       0
2016-06-30 13:00:11.000  4394.25       1
2016-06-30 13:00:11.001  4394.00       0
```